# xml file not shown in android.R.layout

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm creating a fragment for navigation drawer but when I'm using inflater.inflate...
my xml file is not among the options available in android.R.layout...

CODE

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment    
    return inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
  }
```

Comment: Is your R file is there in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
```

Comment: in that case it doesn't recognize R

Comment: clean project and rebuild and try again

Comment: you have to import the correct genereted R class that should be: "your.app.package.R"

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot everyone for answering..
but I got it correctly this way

```
 int view = R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer;
    return inflater.inflate(view, container, false);
```

Comment: you got it working like that cause your IDE auto-imported the correct R class